# iOS Charts - Labelling Columns

Tags: swift, xcode, charts, ios-charts

[image]

In an iOS Charts bar chart I have no problem applying the Y numbers to the columns:

```
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      let dataEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: self.percentageAmount1[i])
      dataEntries1.append(dataEntry1)
      let dataEntry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: self.percentageAmount2[i])
      dataEntries2.append(dataEntry2)
}
```

But how do I label each column, along the X axis, so that you know what they are?

And as a very minor aside any ideas why 100 doesn't appear in the first green column?

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful as iOS Charts is the documentation and examples are few and far between. I was trying to label the columns along the lines of:

```
  let columnTitles = ["Max", "Tilt", "Cloud", "Total"]
  barChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: columnTitles)
```

I have reworked the code adding in a formatter, which works.

```
  let columnTitles = ["Max", "Tilt", "Cloud", "Total"]
  let formatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: columnTitles)
  barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
```

I hope other people will find this useful.

Comment: your first code is using leftAxis, and your second code using xAxis, that the different, not the formatter